# Using ng-click inside a tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I'm using Angular Bootstrap UI and I have a working tooltip.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="helloApp">
  <div ng-controller="helloCtrl as hello"> 
    <a tooltip-trigger="click" tooltip-placement="bottom" uib-tooltip-html="<h1 ng-click='hello.clickInsideToSeeTheWorld()'>Click again!</h1>">Click me to see the tooltip</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('helloApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('helloCtrl', helloCtrl)

function helloCtrl() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.clickInsideToSeeTheWorld = function() {alert(123)}
}
```

When I open up the tooltip, `ng-click` doesn't work. No alert appears. I receive no errors in my console. This is because the HTML isn't compiled. How can I properly compile the tooltip html to get this to work?

Comment: Care to explain why you're downvoting? I find this to be a valid question.

Comment: Change the question name to "Using ng-click inside a tooltip". Also try using `ng-click=$parent.hello.fn()`. It's either a click handler issue or a scoping issue.

Comment: UIB tooltip compiles the template here -- https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L140

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It seems like its a click handler issue. The same issue appears when using your code suggested. I'm lost as to how to fix this.

Comment: Next suggestion -- in your HTML try `<div><h1 ng-click="fn()">...`. That would put the click handler on an element inside the uib-tooltip element's click handler.

Comment: Still nothing. No console error, nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending the previous answer: You can probably use 
    uib-tooltip-template 
instead of 
    uib-tooltip-html 
when you exploit the angular template cache.

I understand that you maybe do not want to create an external template.html, but you do not have to do so. Simply try:

```
    var app = angular.module("test", ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller("testController", function($scope, $templateCache) {

      $scope.clickInsideToSeeTheWorld = function() {
            alert(123) 
      }

      if (!$templateCache.get ('template.html')) {
        $templateCache.put (
          'template.html', 
          '<a ng-click="clickInsideToSeeTheWorld()">Click again!</a>'
        );
      }

    });
```

and

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
<p style="margin-top: 5em;" uib-tooltip-template="'template.html'" tooltip-popup-close-delay="3000" >
   Click me to see the tooltip
</p>
```

Here's an external plunker as well:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Dsi69MQg4NfgOSI5ClFh?p=preview

Comment: This will be the method I use. However since @alyona provided the first correct response I'm giving her credit.

Answer (score 2):

I added uib-tooltip-template instead uib-tooltip-html and changed this to $scope.

index.html

```
<body>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("test", ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller("testController", function($scope) {
      $scope.clickInsideToSeeTheWorld = function() {
            alert(123)}
    });
</script>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">

    <p style="margin-top: 5em;" uib-tooltip-template="'template.html'" tooltip-popup-close-delay="3000" >
       Click me to see the tooltip
    </p>
</div>

</body>
```

template.html

```
<a ng-click="clickInsideToSeeTheWorld()">Click again!</a>
```

Here is working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vh4aNiqEewDmkhzPfmmR?p=preview)

Comment: It is close to impossible for me to use `uib-tooltip-template`. I'll see what I can do and report back.

Comment: According to [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/tooltip/docs), you can't do it with uib-tooltip-html: "Note that this HTML is not compiled. If compilation is required, please use the uib-tooltip-template attribute option instead"

Answer (score 0):

Or Alternative solution is for you to compile code yourself and then assign it to tooltip html

```
var sc = scope.$new( true ); //scope for html
sc.hello = {} // assign your hallo object to new scope
var compiledHtml = $compile( '<h1 ng-click="hello.clickInsideToSeeTheWorld()">Click again!</h1>')( sc );
```

Then you can set tooltip html to compiledHtml.